# What is the best way to mass-save cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I've been working on a rather large program with a lot of JS variables that runs in-browser. What would be the best way to mass-save hundreds of variables and then mass-load them at the press of a button? I was thinking of having a function loop and cycle through every single variable, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cookies? They are being send back to your server every time user opens any page. I'd use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)) and the  [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json)) to save an object with all the properties into a readable entity.

```
var propertiesContainer = { 
  "prop_one": 1,
  "prop_two": 2,
  "prop_three": 3
};
localStorage.setItem("properties", JSON.stringify(propertiesContainer ));
```

After all you can read the properties, by using getItem:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("properties"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyf2xf16/